# Cross_val_predict in SKLearn - expected an array but

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a very simple pandas DataFrame (X), with eight columns, and twenty rows full of floats. Then, I have another DataFrame (y), that is twenty rows. When I run:

```
score = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, scoring='accuracy')
```

I get no error and the results make sense (there is nothing wrong with the DataFrame, basically). However, when I run:

```
predicted = cross_val_predict(clf, X)
```

or

```
predicted = cross_val_predict(clf, X.values)
```

I get the following error:

```
Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got None
```

Any suggestions as to what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with a supervised learning problem, you should also provide `y` as an argument to `cross_val_predict`, i.e., `cross_val_predict(clf, X,y)`. This is necessary, as k fold cross-validation requires training the classifier for multiple training sets.